# how to split and join files in c or rust?

Tags: c++, c, rust

how to split and join files in c or rust?.

I found the split, but saw nothing about joining the files.

I want to split files of various types, from text files to images

want in c or rust because i am using rust, so i can create rust module in c.

[Edit]
I'm making a program that divides files to send by tpc, so I need to divide and merge the files again

Comment: Spit what? From where? How? Why? To what end? This question needs a **lot** more detail before we can even begin to answer. You can't just "split" an image. Do you mean "How can I split a binary file into multiple chunks and then reassemble those later?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C++, you split files by reading the master and writing to one or more new files.
This technique works with the C language also.

Joining files depends if you want to merge or append.  In the append case, the destination file is opened with the "append" and write attribute.  The file pointer is set to the end of the file, then stuff is written (appended) to the file.

IMHO, most file operations should be left to the OS as much as possible.

Comment: could you give an example code to unite?

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ appending to file".

Comment: Downvoter:  Please leave comment as to why you downvoted.